# Vue - How to get current instance from checkbox event?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I tried out this to-do-list app in Vue which I have a checkbox to mark completed to do list item.  How to get current instance from checkbox event? This is what I have done so far.

```js
myObject = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        todos: [{
            id: 1,
            title: 'Learn HTML',
            completed: true
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            title: 'Learn CSS',
            completed: false
          }
        ]
      },
      methods: {
        markComplete() {
          debugger
          this.completed = !this.completed;
        }
      }

    })
```

```css
       .is-complete {
            text-decoration: line-through;
        }
```

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
    <div id="app">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(item,key) in todos" v-bind:class="{'is-complete':item.completed}">
          <input type="checkbox" v-on:change="markComplete" :checked="item.completed"> {{ item.title }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this solution, ( I am a newbie in VUEjs ).

Pass item to `markComplete` function like `v-on:change="markComplete(item)"`, Then toggle the `item.completed`, like

```
markComplete(e) {
   e.completed = !e.completed
 }
```

Check the snippet, hope this is what you are looking for

```js
myObject = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        todos: [{
            id: 1,
            title: 'Learn HTML',
            completed: true
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            title: 'Learn CSS',
            completed: false
          }
        ]
      },
      methods: {
        markComplete(e) {
          e.completed = !e.completed
        }
      }

    })
```

```css
.is-complete {
            text-decoration: line-through;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
    <div id="app">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(item,key) in todos" v-bind:class="{'is-complete':item.completed}">
          <input type="checkbox" v-on:change="markComplete(item)" :checked="item.completed"> {{ item.title }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```